# actual status and future of RFID

Tags: sensor, rfid

I am looking for some expertise on the area of RFID. **What is the actual status of RFID and what will be the future?**
The point is that i have seen a lot of videos, comments, articles and papers about RFID and what great success it will be BUT it was like 2008.

I am of course not just looking for someones opinion, who is just an user, but someone who has more insight and knows what he is talking about. Is there a next big thing or do we only see some containers on ships tagged with RFID.

Comment: It's a very broad question, and we can't answer about the future; though, NFC is the leading technology now.

Comment: I know, but there are some hypes who gets real and some are just hypes on paper. Its not like they are still developing the tech. Its already available, but my milk pack still has a printed price on it.

Comment: Questions should be targeted to real problems, while this is largely hypothetic, and cannot lead to useful answers.

Comment: Ok, so lets focus on the part of the question that is not largely hypothetic but can be answered with facts and some knowledge/experience.

Comment: The status is *many* and the future is *many more*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wet dream in logistics is to replace bar codes on every product with an RFID tag. That's right, also on that 50 cent milk pack. This would allow you to scan a full pallet or shopping cart in a split second. First thing that's needed is an RFID tag which you can read at 1 to 2 meters costing much less than 1 cent.